# Disable a playback device for a certain application?

Tags: windows-10, audio

First off, Windows 10 on an XPS 15 9560 - 7700k

My question stems from a bit of annoyance, and not necessarily a problem...

Basically, I want to disable the Speakers/Headphones device for only one program, Battlefield 1, because I use a Bluetooth headset for it.

Reason being, if I forget to disable the speakers before starting the game, the VoIP system is messed up and I cant hear my teammates. I then have to quit the game, disable the playback device, then restart it. It's very annoying. Usually, I remember to do this before, but all too often I will forget.

The other reason is -- I hate the speakers/headphones being disabled in the first place. I listen to headphones at work and have to re-enable it. It's just a step I would like to avoid having to do in the future. Is there a solution to this without installing a 3rd party software?

Thanks in advance!

Zach

Comment: What happen if you open Volume Mixer and turn off the audio of Battlefield?

Comment: Not sure that would help, shouldn't that turn off Battlefield audio for ALL devices? Either way I'll give it a shot here in a bit!

Comment: Ok, tried this solution and still same problem -- Couldn't hear my teammates. Thanks though.